# Two different outputs generated by SimpleXML on two different servers with the same PHP version

Tags: php, libxml2

I have this code:

```
$feed = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><rss version="2.0" xmlns:yandex="http://news.yandex.ru" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:turbo="http://turbo.yandex.ru" />', LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_ERR_NONE | LIBXML_ERR_FATAL);
$channel = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><channel></channel>', LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_ERR_NONE | LIBXML_ERR_FATAL);
$counter = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><yandex:analytics>test</yandex:analytics>', LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_ERR_NONE | LIBXML_ERR_FATAL);

$toDom = dom_import_simplexml($channel);
$fromDom = dom_import_simplexml($counter);
$toDom->appendChild($toDom->ownerDocument->importNode($fromDom, true));

$toDom = dom_import_simplexml($feed);
$fromDom = dom_import_simplexml($channel);
$toDom->appendChild($toDom->ownerDocument->importNode($fromDom, true));

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->appendChild($dom->importNode(dom_import_simplexml($feed), true));
$dom->formatOutput = true;

var_dump($feed->saveXML());
```

Now, on one server the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:yandex="http://news.yandex.ru" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:turbo="http://turbo.yandex.ru" version="2.0"><channel><yandex:analytics>test</yandex:analytics></channel></rss>
```

And on the second one the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:yandex="http://news.yandex.ru" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:turbo="http://turbo.yandex.ru" version="2.0"><channel><analytics>test</analytics></channel></rss>
```

Both servers have the same PHP version: `7.1.30` the only xml related difference I noticed in two `phpinfo()` is that the first one has `libxml2` `2.9.9` and the other `2.7.6`.

The older one is an old `CentOS 6` system that cannot be upgraded for now unfortunately, and I'm not even sure if that's the `libxml2`'s fault.

Now the problem is that I have a library that depends on the newer behavior.

Is it for sure related to `libxml2` or not?

Can it be worked around somehow without throwing away the library depending on the first behavior?

Comment: It's difficult to test - but your last XML isn't correctly formed, it uses a namespace which isn't declared, try `<yandex:analytics xmlns:yandex="http://news.yandex.ru">`

Comment: https://tech.yandex.com/turbo/doc/rss/example-docpage/ it's yandex's spec actually. :/

Comment: The main thing (for me) is that on it's own - the `$counter` XML is invalid.

Comment: Then maybe it's possible to disable validation in this case? That would solve the problem.

Comment: Just to check - add the namespace declaration that I posted in the first comment, if that solves the problem at least it shows what is happening.

Comment: Yep, it fixes the issue, so you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$counter` XML is invalid, as you have it at the moment...

```
$counter = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
         <yandex:analytics>test</yandex:analytics>', 
     LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_ERR_NONE | LIBXML_ERR_FATAL);
```

The `<yandex:analytics>` is using a namespace which isn't defined in the XML itself.

You should change this to define the namespace...

```
<yandex:analytics xmlns:yandex="http://news.yandex.ru">test</yandex:analytics>
```

or you can add it by creating the element manually before adding it...

```
$fromDom = $toDom->ownerDocument->createElementNS("yandex", "yandex:analytics", "test");
```